# Pasar datos de ajax a php y viceversa

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

estoy haciendo un modal para enviar un correo desde mi página, logro enviar el correo pero no puedo enviar una respuesta al usuario de que su mesaje fue enviado, trabajo con ajax y php, esta es mi funcion ajax:

```html
    function enviamail()
{
    const hnombre= $('#first_name').val();
    const hapellido= $('#last_name').val();
    const hcorreo= $('#email').val();
    const hfono= $('#telephone').val();
    const hcomentarios= $('#comments').val();
   
     // aqui valido que los campos esten llenos
    if(hnombre === '' || hapellido === '' || hcorreo === '' || hfono ==='' || hcomentarios==='' )
    {
          aviso.innerHTML =`<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          <strong>Debe Llenar todos los campos de forma correcta
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </div>`
         
    }
    else
    {
      // si los campos estan llenos los envio a mi php que envia el correo
      aviso.innerHTML ='';
      $.ajax(
            {
                 url:'contacto.php',
                 method:'POST',
                 data: 
                {
                     jnombre:hnombre,
                     japellido:hapellido,
                     jcorreo:hcorreo,
                     jfono:hfono,
                     jcomentarios:hcomentarios,
                }
            }).done(function(respuesta)
                {
                
                  
                  if(respuesta =='enviado')
                  {
                    //si la respuesta que recibo de php es "enviado" muestro este mensaje
                      aviso.innerHTML =`<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                      <strong>Correo enviado correctamente
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </div>`
                     
                      //espero unos segundos y cierro el modal
                      setTimeout(cerrar, 2000);
                      
                     
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    //si la respuesta que recibo de php es "error" muestro este mensaje
                    aviso.innerHTML =`<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    <strong>Ocurrio un error, por favor intente de nuevo
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </div>`
                    //espero unos segundos y cierro el modal
                    setTimeout(cerrar, 2000);
                  }
                }); 

                       
    }
     function  cerrar()
     {
       $('#myModaExp').modal('hide');  
     }
}
```

este de aca es mi codigo PHP

```
    <?php
$asunto = "Comentarios desde la Página";
$destinatario = "contacto@saf.cl";
$nombre=$_POST['jnombre'];
$apellido=$_POST['japellido'];
$correo=$_POST['jcorreo'];
$fono=$_POST['jfono'];
$comentarios=$_POST['jcomentarios'];



$encabezados = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$encabezados .= 'From:'.$nombre.' '.$apellido.' '.'<'.$correo.'>' . "\r\n";


$resultado = mail($destinatario, $asunto, $comentarios, $encabezados); 
//esto no me funiona, no puedo enviar el resultado.
if ($resultado === '') {
    $var = "error";
    $json = json_encode($var);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $json;
} else {
    $var = "enviado";
    $json = json_encode($var);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $json;
}
```

como les comentaba el correo lo envio sin problemas pero es despues de enviar el correo, que necesito enviar la respuesta de "enviado" o "error" de vuleta al ajax, para mostrar los mensajes al usuario, eh eintentado de varias maneras pero no lo consigo.
si me pueden ayudar por favor.

saludos y gracias.

" Me di cuenta que si lo hago de forma local funciona, (no envia el correo pero hace la validación), pero cuando lo subo al hosting definitivo, no funciona"

Comment: QUé significa "no me funciona"?  Has intentado hacer console.log de `respuesta` en tu función javascript? Qué estás recibiendo?

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo, si he hecho console.log y no me muestra nada, es como que despues de enviar el correo y ejecutar el codigo php no vuelve a ingresar a esa parte de la funcion en JS

Comment: Que pasa si omita header('Content-Type: application/json'); ?

Comment: hola @Duston, le saque el header y pasa lo mismo.

Comment: Hola @proteus8, intenta cambiar el "echo" por "return" y haz una console.log para ver la respuesta.

Comment: Hola @CarlosAlbertoMarrufo, gracias por responder, lo cambie por return($json); pero no paso nada, sigue igual.

Comment: Algo debe estar fallando en tu php, lo reviso más a fondo y te doy respuesta más tarde.

Answer (score 0):

El codigo js deberias usar success, done se ejecuta siempre despues de la peticion, no vas a poder recuperar el response.

```
             $.ajax({
                url:'contacto.php',
                method:'POST',
                data:{
                 "jnombre":hnombre,
                 "japellido":hapellido,
                 "jcorreo":hcorreo,
                 "jfono":hfono,
                 "jcomentarios":hcomentarios,
                },
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
```

Tene en cuenta que estas devolviendo un json y comparando texto plano en el codigo js que compartis. lo que quieras devolver desde php lo tenes que devolver con echo. haria algo asi

```
$resultado = mail($destinatario, $asunto, $comentarios, $encabezados); 

echo ($resultado === '') ? "error" : "enviado";
```